# Is it possible to force Windows API calls to always return strings in English (en-us)?

Tags: windows, service, localization

I am working on an application which collects a number of different pieces of system information. One thing I am collecting is a list of services and their descriptions as returned by calling QueryServiceConfig2.

When run on a system configured in a language other than English, the application returns the service names and descriptions in the systems default language. This makes sense but I would like to know if it is possible to force the API calls to return the descriptions in English, assuming the appropriate language pack is installed.

Ideally any solution would need to be compatible with XP and above. I have already tried using the SetThreadLocale function with both en-us (0x0409) and LOCALE_INVARIANT but it did not have any effect.

I did also see the function SetProcessPreferredUILanguages but my application is not a GUI app and also this function is only available on Windows 7 and above.

After multiple days of searching and tests I am at a loss. Is what I am trying to achieve possible?

Comment: Support for localized service [display names](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/nf-winsvc-changeserviceconfigw) and [descriptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/ns-winsvc-service_descriptionw) was added in Windows Vista. Try calling `SetThreadPreferredUILanguages`, to which you can link dynamically in Vista+.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried this as well as `SetProcessPreferredUILanguages` but neither had any effect on the service descriptions returned by `QueryServiceConfig2W`

Comment: I can look into it, but please provide a minimal, complete example using a well-known system service such as "Appinfo", as well as the language packs installed on the system and order of preferred UI languages in the system configuration in the control panel or settings app.